# Get return variable from React.Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My form component has children that contain regular html markup as well a inputs. If the child is a Input I want to add the attachToForm and detachFromForm functions. If it is not an input I want to continue traversing the children to make sure that the element does not have a child input field.

The problem is no matter what I do I cant get traverseChildren to return anything even when using dummy data. Im not sure if im not understanding basic JS or React.children

```
registerInputs(children) {

    React.Children.forEach(children, function(child) {
      if (child.props && child.props.name) {
        this.newChildren.push(React.cloneElement(child, {
            detachFromForm: this.detachFromForm,
            attachToForm: this.attachToForm,
            key: child.props.name
        }))
      } else if (child.props && child.props.children){
        var traverseChildren  = this.traverseChildren(child.props.children, child);
        //this.newChildren.push(traverseChildren);
        console.log(traverseChildren) //=> undefined
      }
    }.bind(this));
    console.log(this.newChildren) // =>[]
 }

traverseChildren(children, current){
    var current = current;
    var me = React.Children.forEach(children, function(child) {
      if (child.props && child.props.name) {
         return React.cloneElement(child, {
            detachFromForm: this.detachFromForm,
            attachToForm: this.attachToForm,
            key: child.props.name
          });
      } else if (child.props && child.props.children){
          return "hello";//this.traverseChildren(child.props.children, current);
      } else {
          return current;
      }
   });
   console.log(me) // => undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React.Children.forEach](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.foreach) does not return a value. It executes the function you provide once per item in the array. Try this:

```
traverseChildren(children, current){
    var current = current;
    React.Children.forEach(children, function(child) {
      if (child.props && child.props.name) {
         return React.cloneElement(child, {
            detachFromForm: this.detachFromForm,
            attachToForm: this.attachToForm,
            key: child.props.name
          });
      } else if (child.props && child.props.children){
          this.traverseChildren(child.props.children, current);
      } else {
          console.log(current);
      }
   });
}
```

Or, maybe you were looking for [React.Children.map](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.map).

Comment: hey @JustinPowell thanks for responding. I have tried something simular to that the problem is It leaves me with only children that are inputs. So when I render this.newChildren I have no labels or titles. I thought by using a second function (traverseChildren) I could keep track of the current child node and add it to the newChildren array if it did not have and input for a child?

Comment: hey  @JustinPowell just realized you did answer the question in the title, so I will open a new question for the other part of my issue. Thanks